# iptables FORWARD port to internal server

Tags: iptables, forwarding, troubleshooting

I've been struggling with a `FORWARD` policy that isn't working the way I'd like, and I can't figure out what is causing the session to fail. I hope someone can help.

My goal is to forward port 3000 from eth0 to an internal Windows machine port 3389 out eth2, so I can RDP into the Windows box. The below configuration script only works with `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`, however I do not want that. I feel better having `iptables -P FORWARD DROP`, but this isn't working for me.

Here is the last version of the script I've been working with. Note that this is the entire script with all my commented stuff included, so you can check everything that's happening here, but keep in mind it's the `FORWARD` part I need help with.

```
echo "Flush firewall and setting default chain policies..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
#iptables --append FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3000 -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT

echo "Enabling firewall with new ruleset..."
# allow ssh to eth0
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# allow http-https traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# allow ping
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j TRACE

# full loopback access
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# minimize http-https DOS attack by limiting burst connections
# may need to adjust this later once web traffic is coming in
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 10/minute --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m limit --limit 10/minute --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT

# all rdp 3000 to jump box
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-prerouting: " --log-level 7
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:3389
#iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j TRACE
#iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3389 -j TRACE
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-forward: " --log-level 7
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

# nat internal network to public interface
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -t nat -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-postrouting: " --log-level 7
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -t nat -j MASQUERADE

# logging
#iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-input: " --log-level 7
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-forward: " --log-level 7
#iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-output: " --log-level 7

# enable ipv4 forwardning for the system
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# add route for private network internet access
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 proto kernel scope link dev eth2

#List iptables ruleset
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Listing iptables..."
iptables -L

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Listing ip routes..."
ip route
```

I've traced the connections, enabled logging rules, etc, but am unable to determine what the issue is based on the information provided. I can spot differences in the traces between `iptables -P FORWARD` default actions, but still not finding the needle in the hay stack.

I'd appreciate any pointers I can get. Thanks!

**Thanks for @HaukeLaging, I've got this working fine. Here is the final script.**

```
echo "Flush firewall and setting default chain policies..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables --append INPUT -t filter -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD -t filter -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT -t filter -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "Enabling firewall with new ruleset..."
# allow ssh to eth0
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# allow http-https traffic
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# ----from private network
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# allow ping
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
# ----from private network
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# full loopback access
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# minimize http-https DOS attack by limiting burst connections
# may need to adjust this later once web traffic is coming in
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 10/minute --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m limit --limit 10/minute --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT

# rdp 3000 to jump box
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT

# nat on public interface
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -t nat -j MASQUERADE

# logging
#iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-input: " --log-level 7
#iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-forward: " --log-level 7
#iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-output: " --log-level 7

# enable ipv4 forwardning for the system
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# add route for private > public access
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 proto kernel scope link dev eth2

#List iptables ruleset
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Listing iptables..."
iptables -L

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Listing ip routes..."
ip route
```

Comment: A general recommendation: Always provide the output of `ip addr` when you want networking problems solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate your commented out rule

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

And you have to correct this one (and the logging rule above, of course):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

That is wrong. If `eth0` is the **output** interface then `192.168.1.2` is the source and not the destination. But why allow state `NEW`? The easiest would be:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

That's a common rule. If you want to keep closer to your connection definition:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -s 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --sport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

**Edit 1:**

And you may need a rule that allows all(?) connections originating from the other system:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state --state NEW -s 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

BTW, quoting the man page:

> The "state" module is an obsolete version of "conntrack".

If you don't use the short rule to allow all established traffic then you also need something like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I should have asked this question a lot sooner. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've lost the ability to reach the internet (http/https) from the Windows machine I am connected to. This did work with my original configuration script, with `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`. Any clue as to why this isn't working now?

Comment: I think I figured it out. `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @JonathanAlmquist See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I used your uptaded conntrack. Just needed to edit like so `iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -s 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT`